# Top exit pages by conversions - No data displayed

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

The following two reports in `Experience Analytics` do not display any graph and show "No data to display".

1. Behavior - Pages - Exit pages - Top exit pages by conversions
2. Behavior - Page URLs - Exit page URLs - Top exit page URLs by conversions

The description for these two reports in the [official document](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/reporting/the_behavior_tab_reports#_Pages) says -

> The exit page/page URLs that have generated the most efficient high
>   value visits on your website.

But these two reports show graphs:

3. Behavior - Pages - Exit pages - Top exit pages by value per visit
4. Behavior - Page URLs - Exit page URLs - Top exit page URLs by value per visit

Then, the reports 1 & 2 should also show some data, according to that definition. Is that correct.

If not, what could be the reason. Is there any configuration to be made like  a goal.

Using Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reports 1 and 2 depend on **conversion** data rather than simply visits. Do you have any goals (and have they been triggered)? You can read more about goals and converting in Sitecore's documentation on the subject:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/reporting/the_experience_analytics_reports_relevant_for_marketers#_The_Conversions_tab
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/reporting/the_conversions_tab_reports